# How to fetch emoji via web scraping?

Tags: python, unicode

I made a simple python script , That scrapes a particular website

Here is the sample code

```
import requests
site='www.example.com'
f=open("text.txt","a")
page = requests.get(site)
contents = page.content
f.write(contents)
f.close()
```

After that I Filtered the data to fetch some text from a particular tag by using this code (not the best approach though)

```
words = []
f = open("text.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    try:
        if(line[0]=="<" and line[1]=="l" and line[2]=="i" and line[3]==">"):
        words.append(line.decode('utf-8'))
    except BaseException,e:
            pass
for a in words:
    print a.encode("utf-8")
```

Although I am successful at fetching my desired data , However the problem arises when i try to fetch text containing an Emoji .

Here is a snippet from my output

```
I am pretty happy ☺ coz i can easily recall this ☝stuff
#x1f60f;&#x1f60f;
```

So any idea how to convert this "#x1f60f" into an emoji ?

P.S - I am trying to save this up in firebase as well but it is still showing these "#x1f60f" up there

Comment: Use the decode function, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604811/python-unicode-character-conversion-for-emoji#answer-41605038)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to take part from #x till the end (`#x1f60f` -> `1f60f`)
2. Complete this part up to 8 bits as Unicode requires by adding `0` at the beginning. `1f60f` -> `0001f60f`
3. Convert.

```
emoji = "\U0001f60f"
print(emoji)
```

[image]

Comment: I wrote the exact same thing on my terminal , but seems like its still printing that "\U0001f60f" :/