# Extract emoji from series of text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, emoji

I have problem extracting emoji from a series.
The code used:

```
import emoji
def extract_emojis(text):
  return ''.join(c for c in text if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI)

for text in df['comments']:
    df['emoji']=extract_emojis(text)
```

Output:

```
             comments                                    | emoji
0     Its very beautiful    
1   Your new bike, @keir ...?   
2   @philip     
3   Any news on the Canadian expansion mentioned i...   
4   Rocky Mountain ❤️   
... ... ...
```

Checking the function on just a text:

```
text = '@philip '
extract_emojis(text)
--> '\U0001f929\U0001f929'
```

Expected result:

```
             comments                                    | emoji
0     Its very beautiful                                 |
1   Your new bike, @keir ...?                            |
2   @philip                                          | 
3   Any news on the Canadian expansion mentioned i...    |
4   Rocky Mountain ❤️                                    | ❤️ 
... ... ...
```

Note:
I have only asked this question after looking at these links:
[Python unicode character conversion for Emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604811/python-unicode-character-conversion-for-emoji) 
[How to extract all the emojis from text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146528/how-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-text)

Comment: What is in `s`?

Comment: I have edited the post and the code, same result @DirtyBit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than iterating over the entire dataset. You can apply the function using `apply` or `lambda`.

```
import pandas as pd 
import emoji
df = pd.DataFrame([['@philip  '],
['Rocky Mountain ❤️']],columns = ['comments'])
```

**Using Lambda:**

```
df['emojis'] = df['comments'].apply(lambda row: ''.join(c for c in row if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI))
df
```

**using Apply**

```
def extract_emojis(text):
    return ''.join(c for c in text if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI)

df['emoji_apply'] = df['comments'].apply(extract_emojis)
df
```

**Output:**

```
comments    emojis
@philip     
Rocky Mountain ❤️   ❤
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but just to increase my understanding, could you tell me why the for loop return empty results?

Comment: @Luc When you do `df['column']` = `some_value` it sets some_value to the entire column. In your case you will see that last executed statement's result is populated in the df.

Comment: Spend 2 hours trying different solutions with many votes. None worked. Only this. Thanks!!