# Extracting Emojis from a dataframe

Tags: python, nlp

My research interest is the effect of emojis in text for sentiment analysis. I would like to extract all the emojis from my dataset. So far I have done the following:

```
 import re 
 from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI


 emoji_1 = re.compile('[\\u203C-\\u3299\\U0001F000-\\U0001F644]')

 emoji_list= list(filter(emoji_1.match, df['Tweet text']))

 emo_found= ' '.join(emoji for emoji in emoji_list)

  

 def get_emoji_set(text):
     return {letter for letter in text if letter in UNICODE_EMOJI['en'] }

 c = get_emoji_set(emo_found)

  Print(c)
```

But it is not extracting all the images. So far I got only the following emojis using the above code:

{'', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''}

However these are only the partial emojis that are present in the dataset. There are also the following emojis present in my dataset which am not getting in the result:

,  , , , ,,,,  + more emojis

Why is my code not extracting all the emojis from my dataset, is there any emojis left as i defined in emoji_1? Is there any more ranges that i should compile using regex ?

I have tried the following answer, but it does not return anything. I get an empty column.

[Extract emoji from series of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63762570/extract-emoji-from-series-of-text)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63762570/extract-emoji-from-series-of-text) worked beautifully for me. Checked other solutions with many votes but they were either using deprecated functions or else did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the [demoji](https://pypi.org/project/demoji/) library might help.

*Accurately find or remove emojis from a blob of text using data from the Unicode Consortium's emoji code repository.*

Comment: I am trying to do it with the following code: `df["Emoji list"] = demoji.findall(df['Tweet text'].map(str))` but getting error 'expected string or bytes like object'